# iOS+Android: Let friends see your location

Tags: android, open-source, ios, geo-location

I am looking for an app that will share my location every 5 minutes (or upon request) to friends.

It should not share the location with others (in particular any server used server should not know my location - so we are talking end-to-end encryption).

I will prefer an app that is open source.